# tensorflow estimator how can i load checkpoint once to predict when a lot of time

Tags: tensorflow, load, tensorflow-estimator

I build a server listen port.  I use tensorflow estimator API build a neural network for predict. But each request will be reload checkpoint file on disk. I think it waste the time. Can i load checkpoint once on server start, not every request arrives.
Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm not sure how you've build this server, but I know what you intend to do, can be done. I've build a Rest API for inference and hosted it on a server. In its source code, I load the checkpoint first and then my main() function starts with @app.route. This way, I'm only considering new input files for inference and this doesn't reload the checkpoint every time. I don't know how much of this helps, but surely posting the code that you've tried already, would help.

Comment: The best solution for this is to use TF Serving. Failing that, Estimator.predict lets you pass an input_fn which can block until the next request arrives, keeping the checkpoint in memory.